# Bootstrap Grid Alignment Issues

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm following a tutorial for RoR but I can't seem to get the alignment right.If I copy and paste the code for the tutorial, it will look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7opt.png)

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

But if I put col-md-1, then it sort of works, looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZZyY.png)

Is it possible to still use col-md-6 but have it properly aligned like the second photo? I don't know what else to change other than the numbers.

Comment: Why do you want to use col-md...are you targetting Medium devices more...i will suggest using sm...and using a pattern as --ROW -> COL-12->COL classes

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test this right now but you may be able to change your first line of your form to:

```
 <%= form_for @user, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
```

This should add the html and css need to make the form horizontal:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal">
```

Some what like this example: https://jsfiddle.net/obp9x1yr/7/

This might be a good post to read for more information: [Rails Bootstrap how to format form_for (width grid collapses)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710486/rails-bootstrap-how-to-format-form-for-width-grid-collapses)